# Windows 7 64bit - 16GB Ram utilizing only 4GB?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I've got 16GB ram and running Windows 7 64bit, but for some reason I think it's utilizing only 4GB?

If I go into properties it says Installed memory: 16.0 GB, but if under some loads for example starting Dreamweaver, Photoshop and some other programs, a Windows error/notice pops up suggesting I should close some programs to prevent information loss due to low memory. If I open the task manger in that situation and add up all the running processes Memory usage, I always seem to end up at 4GB ram.

Let's say I start Photoshop 4 times, each of it will consume 1GB of the memory, this is when Windows will give me the warning that I'm running low on memory.

In msconfig, the memory limitation is not set.

Is there anything else preventing it from utilizing all of my RAM?

Image of the computer properties window
[image]

Comment: If the programs/applications you are using are 32-bit, they will still *each* be subject to a 4GB addressing limitation (and less, practically speaking, because the OS reserves some of that range.)  Have you tried a bona-fide 64-bit program and observed this problem?

Comment: I haven't tried with any explicit 64bit applications, but the applications i'm using won't even reach 4GB at all, what I mean is i'm running multiple applications (let's say I start photoshop 4 times) each of it will consume 1GB of the memory, this is when windows will give me the warning that i'm low on memory.

Comment: Ah; that's more clear.  Suggest you *edit* your question to include that detail.

Comment: What kind of motherboard do you have?  What edition of Windows 7?

Comment: Motherboard: MAXIMUS IV EXTREME-Z and running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot where it shows `Installed Memory` and `System Type`? It is normally the screen you see when you right click on "Computer" from the start menu and go to properties.

Comment: Board should support 16GB.  Hmm.  Tried checking your BIOS settings?  Might there be a setting like "OS Install Mode" or something else potentially limiting your memory?

Comment: [link]http://i.imgur.com/eptMUVd.jpg[link] the requested screenshot. And I did search before for OS install mode, but I couldn't find such an option.

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit processes.

Comment: open task manager and select "view", then "select columns", add GDI Objects to list. If you add up all the GDI numbers is it over or near 10,000 when you get the message?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot or add the exact error message that is given? Is it Windows or the application giving the warning about memory?

Answer (score 3):

Go into your BIOS and look for a setting called "memory remapping". Make sure it is *on*.

Answer (score -1):

1. Let me know your adobe version, because if those are not latest your issue is normal.
2. In Photoshop there is an option to control amount of memory and system cache using by only Photoshop.

Comment: I'm not talking only about Adobe, this happens with any memory intensive application, I could aswell start a game multiple times and it does run into the same problem.

Comment: yes Mrius and chris are right, but I do utilize Photoshop+premier  to use more than 12gb of ram when running 64bit version of both.  all in cs5 edition

Comment: @Marius - this was still a valid suggestion though.  You mentioned multiple Adobe products and Adobe allows a limit to be placed on the memory used cumulativly across all Creative Suite products in use.  Your wording of your question made this appear to be a possibility.