# Windows 7 Professional 64bit 8gb Ram installed 2.98gb usable

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

I've noticed this evening that my Windows 7 (Pro 64 bit) machine is only showing 2.98GB of RAM as usable from a total of 8GB (see 1st image). I've looked at the Task Manager (see 2nd image) and it does look like it's only using a max of approx 3GB.

There's 2 x 4GB chips installed and I've taken them out one at a time and tested each one on it's own in both slots and it always comes in at 4GB installed (2.98GB usable) when there's only one chip in; and 8GB installed (2.98GB usable) when both chips are in.

This machine is a dual boot with Ububtu so I booted into that and it's recognising the full 8GB (see 3rd image).

I've been trying to find an answer for hours and the one that helps most people (msconfig, boot tab -> advanced options, un-tick memory)(see 4th image) is doing nothing when I reboot.

Anyone any ideas why Windows is not picking up all the memory?

Thanks for looking.

Edit 1: The question linked to by other users ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/405579/installed-memory-ram-8gb-4gb-useable)) does not help me. I've gone into my BIOS (press esc when system starts) and I cannot find a `Memory Remapping` section. Unfortunately I have to give this machine over to my wife now and I won't be near it tomorrow. I'll keep looking on Saturday.

Edit 2: Resource monitor (typed `resmon` in Prompt) is showing hardware reserved memory at 5,137mb.

Edit 3: I'm after trying the chips on their own and in each of the two bays. When they're on their own, the hardware reserved is always 1,041MB, no matter the chip or the bay. When combined (in both ways), the hardware reserved RAM is always 5,137MB. This is very annoying. So many similar enough questions out there but none of the solutions are working for me.

[image: Images referenced above]

Comment: They are several duplicates to this question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7), [here](http://superuser.com/questions/312499/windows-7-64-bit-reporting-3-00-gb-usable-memory-with-4-00-gb-installed?rq=1), [here](http://superuser.com/questions/456389/12gb-of-ram-only-8gb-is-usable-on-windows-7-64-bit?rq=1), and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/558419/windows-7-64bit-16gb-ram-utilizing-only-4gb?rq=1)

Comment: Possible dupe: [Installed Memory (RAM): 8GB (4GB Useable)](http://superuser.com/q/405579)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed Memory (RAM): 8GB (4GB Useable)](http://superuser.com/questions/405579/installed-memory-ram-8gb-4gb-useable)

Comment: "(see 1st image) (see 2nd image)" What images???

Comment: Damn I cut them from the beginning yesterday then forgot to paste at the end. Will do now. Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help with this? As I said, there's no memory remapping in my BIOS, I've read all the supposed 'duplicate' questions and nothing is working. I can't understand how Ubuntu can see and use the full memory available but Windows is saying only 2.98gb available

Answer (score -1):

Wow, just wow. I feel like an almighty tool.

So it turns out the problem is as follows. When I turn my machine on (a dual boot with Ubuntu), I'm given the options in this screen [here](https://i.imgur.com/CEZ4ocx.jpg)

If I boot into the bottom one (/dev/sda2) I only get 2.98GB of usable RAM (I was pressing the end key on keyboard then return for ease).

If I boot into the second last one (/dev/sda1) I get 7.86GB of usable RAM.

I suspect the second partition equates to my System (D:) drive which for whatever reason doesn't give the full amount of RAM.

Problem solved. Thanks to everyone who looked.

If anyone's feeling kind, can they please upvote me so I can post images properly the next time I have a question.